# CakePHP - Linking Models

Tags: cakephp

I have three models

1. User
2. Status
3. Comments

I am done with User and Status associations now i want to make join for comments but i am a bit confused and i think it would be like this...

Scenario 1: A user hasMany status and status belongsTo user [ DONE ]
Scenario 2: A status hasMany comments and comments belongsTo status [ Which will be done as well ]

The thing which is eating my mind is that comments also belongsTo user [ Right or Wrong ? ]

If right then is this the way i am gonna use belongsTo

```
var $belongsTo = array('status','user');
```

and what about find('all') ? would it be like this

```
$this->User->Status->Comment->find('all');
```

Comment: What do you mean by the `Status` model? You can make a summary of your application?

Comment: Status is same as on Facebook .... A status can have multiple comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on application that looks like Facebook, I think you should have these associations like:

**User**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
);
```

**Status**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),
);
```

**Comment**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'status_id'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),
);
```

And to find comments of a status, for example, you can use **[Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)**.

Hope this helps.